# ncmpcpp sorting causes song duplication

Tags: music-player, mpd, ncmpcpp

On the view `1`, after `ctrl+s` (sort all songs by) the songs are sorted but also duplicated. Additional sorting after that does not duplicate them further.

Image:

[image]

How can I prevent this duplication ? What causes this behaviour ?

Comment: I know this is off topic, but can you share your ncmpcpp config? The colors look very nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove my current playlists and add them again.

There are no song duplications after this.